# How to change the default data type from text to json for a ServiceStack POCO?

Tags: json, postgresql, servicestack

This is specific to PostgreSQL, but I'd still like to know if it's possible.

Given this example

```
public class Borrower
{
    public Borrower()
    {
        PhoneNumbers = new Dictionary<PhoneType, string>();
        Addresses = new Dictionary<AddressType, BorrowerAddress>();
    }

    [AutoIncrement] // Creates Auto primary key
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Index(Unique = true)] // Creates Unique Index
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<PhoneType, string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }  //Blobbed
    public Dictionary<AddressType, BorrowerAddress> Addresses { get; set; }  //Blobbed
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}



var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("Database:MyDatabase"), PostgreSqlDialect.Provider);

using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<BorrowerAddress>();
    db.DropAndCreateTable<Borrower>();


    var customer = new Borrower
    {
        FirstName = "Orm",
        LastName = "Lite",
        Email = "stephenpatten@foo.com",
        PhoneNumbers =
          {
              { PhoneType.Home, "555-1234" },
              { PhoneType.Work, "1-800-1234" },
              { PhoneType.Mobile, "818-123-4567" },
          },
        Addresses =
          {
              { AddressType.Work, new BorrowerAddress { 
                Line1 = "1 Street", Country = "US", State = "NY", City = "New York", ZipCode = "10101" } 
              },
          },
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
    };

    var customerId = db.Insert(customer, selectIdentity: true); 
    customer = db.Single<Borrower>(new { customer.Email });
    Debug.Assert(customer.Id == customerId, "Ids are the same");
}
```

After this is executed, here is the schema for the borrower table

[image: Borrower Table]

and the data just inserted as json.

[image]

So my question is, "Can I change the datatype on the POCO via an attribute or some other mechanism to support the json datatype?"

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the datatype using the `[CustomField]` attribute, e.g:

```
public class Borrower
{
    ...
    [CustomField("json")]
    public Dictionary<PhoneType, string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; } 
}
```

But whilst that will let you create a table with a `json` field, you still won't be able to able to Insert records with OrmLite as it requires some [advanced customizations with the Ngpqsl PostgreSQL Driver](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/wiki/How-to-add-a-custom-type-to-Npgsql). We'll look at adding deeper integration with Npgsql to support this in future.